# Do I need Visual Studio 2008 to install Visual Studio .NET?

Tags: windows-7, installation, editing, visual-studio, asp.net

I can't seem to install Visual Studio .NET on my Windows 7 machine (64 bit). Do I need Visual Studio 2008 to install?

I'm also looking for a good ASP.NET editor (which supports Intellisense), any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need Visual Studio 2008 for Windows 7 (though the 2005 version should also install).

If you haven't got access to the full version then I'd recommend getting the [Express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/).

You will need the [Web Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) version.

Answer (score 2):

What was the message you got from the VS2005 installer that stopped you from installing it?

It should work as long as you run it as Administrator (Right-Click -> "Run as Administrator...". You will need to apply [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=BB4A75AB-E2D4-4C96-B39D-37BAF6B5B1DC&displaylang=en) and the [SP1 Update for Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=90E2942D-3AD1-4873-A2EE-4ACC0AACE5B6&displaylang=en) after you have installed it. There are similar steps you will need to follow to install SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition.

More specifics on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477162/installing-visual-studio-2005-on-windows-7-x64), "Installing Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7 X64".

Visual Studio is pretty good for [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), take a look at [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx).